# How to click on link with specific text with Pyppeteer

Tags: python, web-scraping, text, hyperlink, pyppeteer

I am trying to click a link with specific text. It is a button to log out from website.

[image: screenshot of dropdown menu]

```
button = await page.xpath("//a[contains(., 'Abmelden')]")
```

The above should select the right element via xpath. But how can I click it?

Syntax is unfortunately a bit different to original Puppeteer.

I tried

```
button = await page.xpath("//a[contains(., 'Abmelden')]")
await page.click(button)
```

But then I get

```
TypeError: Object of type ElementHandle is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 0):

[`xpath()` returns a list](https://miyakogi.github.io/pyppeteer/reference.html#pyppeteer.page.Page.xpath), so you'll want to index into that list to get an element handle. Once you have an element handle, you can call `handle.click()` directly. If you pass a parameter to click, it should be a string selector, not a handle.

Example:

```py
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch


async def main():
    browser = await launch({"headless": True})
    [page] = await browser.pages()
    await page.setContent("""
    <body>
      <a href="#">Abmelden</a>
      <script>
      const a = document.querySelector("a");
      a.addEventListener("click", e => a.textContent = "clicked");
      </script>
    </body>
    """)
    [button] = await page.xpath("//a[contains(., 'Abmelden')]")
    await button.click()
    print(await page.Jeval("a", "el => el.textContent")) # => clicked
    await browser.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

If the trusted click above fails, you can try issuing an untrusted click with:

```py
await page.evaluate("el => el.click()", button)
```

If this isn't working on your live site, there is probably some additional behavior that accounts for it:

- an iframe
- a shadow root
- the page detecting your bot and blocking you
- visibility/scroll
- asynchronous JS behavior or waiting for a response to arrive and mutate the DOM
- surprising event listener behavior on the element you're clicking
- ...

Comment: In my case list slicing was necessary on this stage: `await page.evaluate('(btn) => btn.click()', button[0])`. Without it i got an error like @weather did.

Comment: @Darkitechtor you probably have a list of buttons, or didn't unpack the xpath return iterable as shown in my answer (`[button] =`). Technically, `button[0]` is an index, not a slice, which uses `[:]` syntax.